# Python beatifulSoup2 multiple tag extraction from XML

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

This is my XML:

```
...
<class>
<ident>value1</ident>
<ident>value2</ident>
<ident>value3</ident>
</class>
... so on (multiple class elements)
```

My python code:
        soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('new.xml', 'r').read(), 'lxml-xml')

```
soup=bs4.BeatifulSoup(open('file.xml','r').read(), 'lxml-xml')
class_obj = {}
#code here to add all class elements into class_obj ...
for i in class_obj:
       print class_obj[i].ident.string
```

Output:

```
value1
```

It is only fetching 1 string from the first  tag and skipping other  tags. And need to continue this for nested tags. There are multiple  tags and each  tag has multiple  tags.

Help!!!

Comment: You are using Python 2.7? Why not upgrade to the latest? 2.7 has been officially put out of service starting 1-Jan-2020.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `findAll` or `select` which will return for you a `list` you can iterate over.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<class>
<ident>value1</ident>
<ident>value2</ident>
<ident>value3</ident>
</class>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("ident"):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

Comment: What if I want to do it for nested tags like there are multiple <class> and each <class> has multiple <ident> ? I want to print all <ident> values of all <class> tags

Comment: @kaosantix12 then you've to assign the `attribute`, something like `select("class indent")`